# Changing the language of the web page

Tags: php

I have created a simple form to  change the language of the labels and buttons using php. Two `ini` files were created called `EN.ini` and `TI.ini`. Although language of labels gets changed, buttons are still unchanged.

please help me to solve this problem.
here is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $L["title"];?></title>
</head>
    <body>

    <?php

        if(isset($_GET["lang"])){

            $L=parse_ini_file($_GET["lang"].".ini");

        }else{
            $L=parse_ini_file("en.ini");
        }
    ?>

    <a href="?lang=en">EN</a>
    <a href="?lang=it">IT</a>
    <a href="?lang=sin">SIN</a>


    <h1><?php echo $L["Login form"];?></h1>

    <form action="login_action.php" method="post">

        <fieldset>


            <label><?php echo $L["un"];?></label>
            <input type="email" name="email"/> <br/> <br/>

            <label><?php echo $L["pw"];?></label>
            <input type="password" name="pword"/>

            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>

            <input type="button" value=" <?php echo $L['reset'];?>" />
            <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $L['login'];?>" />


        </fieldset>
    </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be problem is - filename "EN.ini" but file name after $_GET["lang"].".ini" will be en.ini

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a very insecure solution as it can be easily hacked to include other files.

That said you should change the names on your link should change the outcome. Remember, if you are working on Linux, it is all case sensitive.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $L["title"];?></title>
</head>
    <body>

    <?php

        if(isset($_GET["lang"])){

            $L=parse_ini_file(strtoupper($_GET["lang"]).".ini");

        }else{
            $L=parse_ini_file("en.ini");
        }
    ?>

    <a href="?lang=en">EN</a>
    <a href="?lang=it">IT</a>
    <a href="?lang=sin">SIN</a>


    <h1><?php echo $L["Login form"];?></h1>

    <form action="login_action.php" method="post">

        <fieldset>


            <label><?php echo $L["un"];?></label>
            <input type="email" name="email"/> <br/> <br/>

            <label><?php echo $L["pw"];?></label>
            <input type="password" name="pword"/>

            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>

            <input type="button" value=" <?php echo $L['reset'];?>" />
            <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $L['login'];?>" />


        </fieldset>
    </form>

    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tries to change INPUT to BUTTON

`<button type="submit"><?= echo $L['login']; ?></button>
<button type="button"><?= echo $L['reset']; ?></button>`